# what does "an empty MaybeLocal" mean?

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm starting work with nodejs addons using Nan and am reading about MaybeLocal.

The docs say "If an API method returns a MaybeLocal<>, the API method can potentially fail either because an exception is thrown, or because an exception is pending, e.g. because a previous API call threw an exception that hasn't been caught yet, or because a TerminateExecution exception was thrown. In that case, an empty MaybeLocal is returned."

Is this roughly the equivalent of returning a null pointer but with a simple class that can detect that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(V8 developer here.) Yes, an "empty MaybeLocal" is essentially a pointer that can be `nullptr` and forces the code to check for that case.

The background is that due to the nature of JavaScript, many of V8's API operations can (somewhat unexpectedly) fail: any time any JavaScript is executed, that JavaScript code might throw an exception. Even reading an object property could invoke a getter. We have learned from experience that it is exceedingly difficult to write client code that correctly checks for all these, so nowadays V8's API is mostly based on `MaybeLocal`s that help you find all the places that need `nullptr` checks -- or `.IsEmpty()` checks, as they're called in the `MaybeLocal` world.

In cases where you can guarantee that a `MaybeLocal` cannot be empty, you can use `.ToLocalChecked()`, which will crash if the `MaybeLocal` was empty. Otherwise, a common pattern is:

```
Local<Value> value;
if (maybe_value.ToLocal(&value)) {
   // Do stuff with {value}.
} else {
   // Handle error. If you have a TryCatch, it should
   // have caught an exception.
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the background explanation. I'm finding that's the hardest thing to acquire. There's a lot of code to read but not much "here's why it's done this way".